How to map my windows 11 Audio to a gradio application running on Ubuntu EC2 instance?
How to map my windows 11 Audio to a gradio application running on Ubuntu EC2 instance ?
I am trying to run a gradio Audio application inside Ubuntu EC2. I am using picovoice to detect the wakeword. The PVRecorder module fails as it could not detect any sound card on EC2.
Have tried pulse audio.. but no success.
